# how to get height value before click event?

Tags: jquery

I tried to get height of div block before each click event in jquery and have to set as a global variable for some action.

Currently, I'm handling slide up/down action, I want to set height for slide up before each click event. I tried various way but its failed. Anyone suggest me how to get the value.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Well, your question is a little bit less described. But I try it. Did you ever heard something about deferred objects? (https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

Comment: In the "various ways" that you "tried", did you at all stumble across the jQuery `.height()` function?  https://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: @david, yes I tried that also but it doesn't help.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt to understand your problem a bit better?

Comment: @jinfy: What's different about your code that the `.height()` function doesn't get the height of the matched element?  What did you try?  What was the result?  What was the expected result?  Why?  Currently you're just asking how to get the height of an element.  That's exactly what `.height()` does.  If you've *tried something* and it's *not working* then explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as that

```
var somevar = $('#someDiv').height();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the current div height this code:

```
var divHeight = $('#yourDiv').height(); // get div height
```

Set the current div height this code:

```
$("#yourDiv").css("height", '100px');  // set div height
```

Comment: would it be possible to add some description to yhe code you posted